# Azure Function timeout event, reasons

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics

I have Azure Function app and have function inside:

```
[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Singleton]
[Function(nameof(FunctionDataUsageParseFromBlobFile))]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"{functionName} function processed: {DateTime.UtcNow} UTC.");
```

so, after starting it logs string about started (and UTC time)

it works fine and look like following:

[image]

so, it's ok

But sometimes I got timeout exception of execution (not only for this function, for other functions inside this app too, this is only as example):

> Timeout value of 00:09:59 exceeded by function
> 'Functions.FunctionDataUsageParseFromBlobFile' (Id:
> '91921e6e-8ddf-48c0-b846-6c69dd61a369'). Initiating cancellation.

and the following full-cycle of function execution look like:

[image]

As we can see, only 3 messages in `traces` for the call, 2 from them are technical (Executing/Executed) and third - about timeout.
So, it's not an error inside function, because even first line was not logged, where an error is not possible. It looks like problem is not at function at all, function had not been started at all.

Why it happened and how to localize this problem? My idea to increase scale app service plan, but I don't have to observe and need to solve problem now.
Any other place to see detailed error and why it happened?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the `Consumption plan`, the maximum time for each invocation of your function is [10 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale). If the work your function is doing goes beyond it, it will be terminated by the Azure Function runtime host. You need to upgrade your service tier [to `Premium`] to get more execution time.

If your logic of parsing the blob file can be broken down to set of activities, then you can use the 'Durable function' approach, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#application-patterns).

Comment: I'm not sure, that problem is in duration time. No messages about function is being started. It looks like function is frozen sometimes, by unknown reasons. And it happens with other functions too, randomly...

Comment: You mean to say, the body of your function seems not executed as you don't see traces of Entity Framework? Try a fresh build and deploy it. Is there any initialisation code that failed with no logging?

Comment: yes, the same behavior. Or real no execution at all, or just no logging...

Comment: Turn off `sampling` for your app insights, so that you don't miss any of the logs.